# Cypress: Using Variable in cy.get

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to get different elements with names listed in an array

```
const List = ['Age', 'Name', 'Creation']

cy.get('*[value^=${List[0]}]').should('not.have.class','errand-cui')
cy.get('*[value^=${List[1]}]').should('not.have.class','errand-cui')
```

This doesn't work. Is that even possible the way I try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Template literals use backticks in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) The following should work:

```js
cy.get(`*[value^="${List[0]}"]`).should('not.have.class', 'errand-cui');
```

Additionally, you could use `.each()` to iterate through all elements if they have a common selector.

```js
cy.get('foo') // common selector for the elements
  .each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).should('not.have.class', 'errand-cui');
  });
```